# VueJS - Set CSS class to answered questions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a Quiz App. I have question selection menu. Each box is one question. I'd like to set a CSS class to each question's box if the question has been answered.

This is how I generate Question boxes

```
<input
        v-for="(question, i) in questions"
        :key="i"
        :value="i + 1"
        v-bind:class="[i === index ? 'current' : '', answers[index] ? 'answered' : '']"
        @click="chooseQuestion(i)"
        class="questionbox"
        type="button"
      />
```

As you can see

```
v-bind:class="[i === index ? 'current' : '', answers[index] ? 'answered' : '']"
```

I tried doing this. The first ternary if is for current selected question, and that works perfectly! The second one is my try to make it work.

It works only if selected answer has been answered and it sets CSS class to all other boxes.

I have an array in which answers are saved and connected to each question. How to make a function to always monitor that array and check if **answers[question_index]** has any answers?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], like codesandbox

Comment: Looks like you've confused `i` and `index` in your second ternary.

Comment: Oh wow. Indeed. What a stupid mistake. Thank you Duroth. But I still have one small problem, after removing answers from previously answered question the CSS class remains present. **answers[i]** is not enough of a check because array stays full but this time with **answer_index: false** while before answering it is empty. Do you have any quick workaround for this? I need to check if there is **any** **answer_index** set to **true** Thank you :)